# Why doesn't Google Chrome show up in the "Default Applications" list in Gnome 3?

Tags: gnome, gnome3, chrome, gnome-shell, defaults

I'd like to configure Google Chrome as my default web browser on Arch Linux.  I've already done the following:

- Made sure I have a `~/.local/share/applications/google-chrome.desktop` which has an `Exec` line that contains a `%U`
- Pointed everything related to web browsing in `~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list` to `google-chrome.desktop`

But still when I go to Settings -> Details -> Default Applications the "Web" dropdown menu doesn't include Google Chrome as one of the choices, and `xdg-open` still launches Firefox.

What am I missing here?  Why doesn't Google Chrome show up in the Default Applications list?

---

*System details:*
Gnome Shell version 3.16.3
Google Chrome installed from AUR
Arch Linux

Comment: I don't have a `~/.local/share/applications/google-chrome.desktop` and things work fine for me. Did you add that manually? If so, did you add a `MimeType` field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what the issue was, but after uninstalling Firefox and deleting the following files everything seems to be working:

```
~/.local/share/applications/wine*
~/.local/share/applications/defaults.list
~/.local/share/applications/mimeinfo.cache
```

I'm not sure if it was the uninstall of Firefox or the removal of those files that made things work...  None of those files had any reference to web browsing, Firefox, or Google Chrome.

Note that I left `~/.local/share/applications/google-chrome.desktop` there, so I guess that wasn't causing any problems.